# Component creation fails under UAC admin, works without UAC elevation

Tags: com, registry, registration, win32com

I have a **.NET COM dll** with a custom registration procedure so it gets registered under **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes** as opposite to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE**. So there are the following keys (current user is the admin on the Windows 7 PC):

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\My.ProgId\CLSID
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\CLSID\{XYZZYZYZYZ-YZYZY-ZYZYZY} etc
```

If I build a simple C++ client:

```
hr = CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("My.ProgId"), &clsid);
```

and run it without **UAC elevation (Windows 7)**, it creates the component successfully.
On the other hand, if I run with elevation on, it fails with `Invalid class string`.

I've inspected with process monitor, when it works it looks for the **HKCU\Software\Classes\My.ProgID** key and that opens ok. When it fails (elevation on) it looks for **HKCR\My.ProgId** and errors with `NAME NOT FOUND`. Opening the registry key manually from `classes_root` is successful though:

```
HKEY key;
RegOpenKey( HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, _T( "My.ProgId"), &key);
```

Please help! Thanks

Comment: It seems to be related to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756926.aspx

Comment: Does anyone know a workaround ? Are there some other registry keys that I should add so it works with elevation on ?